# Getting errors trying to run shell script (Linux)

Tags: linux, bash, linux-mint, bash-scripting, sh

I'm trying to run the following script. I have run it before without issue, but now I encounter an error.

```
#!/bin/bash
# init
function pause(){
   read -p "$*"
}

   echo & echo "(Website):" &&read input
   output=$(ping -c 1 "$input" 2>/dev/null)
   if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
   ip=$(printf '%s' "$output" | gawk -F'[()]' '/PING/{print $2}'  2>/dev/null)
   clear
   echo
   echo "$ip"; 
   echo -n $ip | xclip -selection c
   echo
   echo
   echo IP copied to clipboard.
   echo
   echo && sleep 2
   pause 'Press [Enter] key to exit...'
   exit
else
   clear
   echo
   echo "Host not found";
   echo && sleep 1
   pause 'Press [Enter] key to exit...'
   exit
fi
```

But now all of a sudden it results in the following error:

```
3: /home/username/Desktop/shell.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I have not made any changes to the script itself, and I don't understand why this bracket results in an error now. Does anybody see anything in this script that I have missed?

Bash version: 4.2.45(1)-release
fresh install, mint 16 (updated everything)

EDIT: I'll put this here so I can actually show what happens.
I ended up removing the pause function completely:

```
#!/bin/bash
# init

   echo & echo "(Website):" && read input
   output=$(ping -c 1 "$input" 2>/dev/null)
   if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
   ip=$(printf '%s' "$output" | gawk -F'[()]' '/PING/{print $2}'  2>/dev/null)
   clear
   echo
   echo "$ip"; 
   echo -n $ip | xclip -selection c
   echo
   echo
   echo IP copied to clipboard.
   echo
   echo && sleep 2
   exit
else
   clear
   echo
   echo "Host not found";
   echo && sleep 1
   exit
fi
```

But when I run "sh ~/Desktop/shell.sh" I get this:

```
: not found/Desktop/shell.sh: 3: /home/username/Desktop/shell.sh:  
(Website):
```

(I type google.com and press enter) and it returns

```
: bad variable name/shell.sh: 4: read: 
: not found/Desktop/shell.sh: 5: /home/username/Desktop/shell.sh: 
/home/username/Desktop/shell.sh: 24: /home/username/Desktop/shell.sh: Syntax error: word unexpected
```

Thank you all for the replies, is there something wrong with the shell itself?

Comment: I tried your code, works for me. What version of bash is it running? `echo $BASH_VERSION`. You can delete the '()' on line 3; you're declaring the function with the `function` keyword and the open bracket.

Comment: Hello, the version output is '4.2.45(1)-release'.

Comment: When I remove the (), the following errors are now being returned:

   "bad variable name/shell.sh: 4: read:"  and "Syntax error: word unexpected"

Comment: What happens if you remove line 3 and rewrite it?
I've experienced similar issues when I started editing with a different editor (e.g. notepad, bluefish, ...). There could be a hidden character in your script that prevents normal execution.

Comment: I ended up removing the function completely

Comment: (1) Is there any possibility that your script file has carriage return characters in it? (2) Why do you say `echo & echo "(Website):"`? Are you deliberately putting the first `echo` into the background? (That shouldn’t be causing the problems you’re reporting, but it seems odd.) (3) Please indent your code properly. The `if` (and any statements not in the `if`-`then`-`else` block) should be at the same indentation level as the `else` and the `fi`. (Again, that shouldn’t be causing the problem, but it hurts my eyes to look at incorrectly indented code.)

Comment: that is not in the script, I did that as I was indenting for the site. I ended up re-typing the entire thing into a new file. the & is just something I kind of got used to on windows and serves no real purpose

Answer (score 0):

I take back one of the previous version of your script. It's not needed to erase the function.

When I run the script with `\bin\bash MyScript.sh` seems to function properly.
If instead I run it with `\bin\sh  MyScript.sh` it give me errors.

**Why?**
In many distributions `\bin\sh` is a *symlink* to `dash`, in other to `bash`, in other can be the original `sh`.

If you change with `chown u+x MyScript.sh` the permission of the script and after you will execute it with `./MyScript.sh` the system will use the first line to understand with which `shell` execute it. You can read more about the [*shebang* e.g. here](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/)

If instead you run the script with `sh MyScript.sh` you *force* the script to be executed with a different shell (in this case `/bin/sh`).

```
#!/bin/bash  

function pause(){  
   read -p "$*"  
}  

printf "\n(Website):" &&read input
output=$(ping -c 1 "$input" 2>/dev/null)
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  ip=$(printf '%s' "$output" | gawk -F'[()]' '/PING/{print $2}'  2>/dev/null)
  clear                                              
  printf "\n${ip}";   
  echo -n $ip | xclip -selection c            
  printf "\n\nIP copied to clipboard.\n\n\n"
  sleep 2 
  pause 'Press [Enter] key to exit...'  
  exit 0  
else
  clear 
  printf "\n\n Host not found\n\n" 
  sleep 1  
  pause 'Press [Enter] key to exit...'  
  exit 1 
fi
```

Note:
I change many `echo` with `printf`, because in this case it is more compact.
With `printf` you have to remember to put `\n` to have a newline, `\t` for a tab and so on...

Answer (score -1):

Remove the two parentheses `()` from the definition of your function, so it looks like this:

```
function pause {
    …
}
```

And this error:

> bad variable name/hey.sh: 4: read: Syntax error: word unexpected

Is because of this:

```
&&read input
```

That should be like this:

```
&& read input
```

Just tried this with bash 4.2.47-2 on fedora linux 20 64 bits.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. It results in an error for me, even if I remove the "pause" function from the script entirely, it says "bad variable name/hey.sh: 4: read:"

Comment: No, there doesn’t need to be white space after (or before) `&&`.

Comment: Now, it begins by telling me ": not foundhey.sh:", yet continues with the script. When I give it a host name and press enter, the same errors occur. I have removed the function for pause completely, and spaced the "&& read" but still these errors happen. This very script worked fine with linux mint 14, but I installed 16 this morning if that helps.

Comment: Did you try updating your version of the shell?

Comment: I updated everything through the update manager, but I did not update the shell in particular.. ?

Comment: try apt-get update bash

Comment: "E: The update command takes no arguments"

Comment: I did run apt-get update this morning though

Comment: Have you tried running this with another shell interpreter?

Comment: No, I was only aware of bash